# Spring Boot Security - Thymeleaf sec:authorize-url not working

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-java-config

The **sec:authorize-url** Tag does not work with Spring boot security by default:

```
git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot
```

#### Project spring-boot-sample-web-method-security:

Add dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Adapt the controller from the sample:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String home(Map<String, Object> model) {
model.put("message", "Hello World");
model.put("title", "Hello Home");
model.put("date", new Date());
return "home";
}

@RequestMapping("/admin/foo")
public String home2(Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("message", "Hello World");
    model.put("title", "Hello Home");
    model.put("date", new Date());
    return "home";
}
```

Add url matching to application security:

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
    .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
...
```

Add testcode in home.html

```
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    has role admin
 </div>
 <div sec:authorize-url="/admin/foo">
    can see /admin
 </div>
```

When I start the app and login I will always see the "can see /admin" part no matter if I can actually access the url or not. The role evaluation itself works as expected, as does the url permission itself (I get a 403 when I try to access it with ROLE_USER).

If I add a dummy privilegeEvaluator to the web security configuration that simply returns false for every request, the *div* will disappear correctly.

Am I missing something here? Is this expected behaviour and what do I need to define to make authorize-url work that way it used to when configuring security with xml?

## Update: Basic authentication

This issue is connected to Basic authentication and its AutoConfiguration in **SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration**:

In **SampleMethodSecurityApplication** change the ApplicationSecurity order by replacing:

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
```

with

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER + 1)
```

and deactivate basic in spring boot **application.properties**

```
security.basic.enabled: false
```

Now the authorize-url tag will work as expected, but you have lost http basic AutoConfiguration of course.

Leaving **security.basic.enabled: true** and changing the order of the ApplicationSecurity to be higher than BASIC_AUTH_ORDER will leave you with Basic authentication instead of form login...

## Update - PrivilegeEvaluator

I have found the following workaround. Simply register the security interceptor manually in your SecurityConfig:

```
@Order(SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER)
protected static class ApplicationSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        final HttpSecurity http = getHttp();
        web.postBuildAction(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                web.securityInterceptor(http.getSharedObject(FilterSecurityInterceptor.class));
            }
        });
    }
```

It allows you to use the recommended ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER and http basic auto configuration. I have posted more details [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1319#issuecomment-56345581)
Any explanation why this works is appreciated.

Comment: I have encountered the exact same issue. 

During debugging I've found that `DefaultWebInvocationPrivilegeEvaluator` evaluates the permissions using a different `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` then what the real filter does. The `AbstractSecurityInterceptor` used by `DefaultWeb..` only contains a single record - `/** - hasAnyRole(USER, ADMIN)`.

I have not found a way to solve this. Have you found anything since you posted the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using **thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4** should solve the problem

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
</dependency>
```